# show that a functions derivative is bounded below by $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a differentiable function: $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=1$ and $f'(x) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$. I need to show $f'(x)\geq e^x$ for all $x$.

At first this appeared to be obvious but i am having trouble showing it rigorously. It seemed obvious because of $(e^x)'=e^x$ and we are assuming that $f'(x)\geq f(x)$. a thought i had was to define another function $h(x)=e^{-x} f(x)$ and then differentiate and try to obtain the inequality but its getting me nowhere. i.e. $h'(x) = e^{-x}f'(x) - e^{-x}f(x)$ then using the assumptions to try and make the inequality true, by saying that $e^xh'(x) = f'(x)-f(x)$ but I'm not coming out with the required result.

is there ant theorems or results i can apply or am i being silly and missing something?

EDIT: could this just be deduced by proving the derivative of the exponential function and then saying that since $f'(x)\geq f(x)$ then $f'(x)\geq e^x$ because the derivative of the $e^x$ is $e^x$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want $f(0) = 1$ otherwise $f(x) = 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thats what i meant, just made a little typo :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your approach will work if you just notice that

$$h'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))\ge0$$

for all $x\ge0$, which implies $e^{-x}f(x)=h(x)\ge h(0)=1$.

As an alternative approach, let $g(x)=f(x)-e^x$, so that $g(0)=0$. Then

$$g'(x)=f'(x)-e^x\ge f(x)-e^x=g(x)$$

But $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x\ge0$ imply $g(x)\ge0$ for all $x\ge0$.  But I like your approach better.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac d {dx} \log(e^x) = 1 \le \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac d {dx} \log f(x)
$$
Now apply the mean value theorem to $g(x)= \log f(x)$: For $a>0$, we have
$$
\frac{g(a) - g(0)}{a-0} = g'(c) \ge 1 \text{ for some }c>0.
$$
Thus $g(a)\ge a$ for all $a\ge 0$.  If $\log f(a) \ge a$ then $f(a) \ge e^a$.

The reason why the mean value theorem is essential here is that the theorem is false if there is any gap in the domain.